# What is an action (in one word) that makes you say "goodbye"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there some verb that represents an action of "saying goodbye" ?

*Example:*

> When you meet someone, you say ***hello***.
>
> When you ____ (with) someone, you say ***goodbye***.

When a pair does this it is called "break up".

Comment: Depart? Separate.

Comment: *To break up* with someone means to end a romantic relationship. *To part* or *take leave* is to say goodbye.

Comment: And by *pair* I think you mean *couple*: although these words are normally synonyms, *couple* is used to refer to two people in a romantic relationships while *pair* isn't generally. e.g.: “Are they a pair?” “Uh, yes, they are two people.” “No, I mean are they a couple?” “Oh! Yes, they started dating yesterday.”

Comment: Use whatever word you think best suggests the reason for parting.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The verb you are looking for is ***[part](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/part)***

> to go apart from or leave one another, as persons

[Dictionary.com, sense 23.]

In your case,

> When you ***part*** with someone, you say goodbye.

Comment: Many words describe either the action of leaving, or of being left.
"Part" is excellent since it fits both.

Comment: +1, but I can't decide whether I like "part from" or "part with" more.

Comment: @dcshannon - that could make a good ELU question!

Answer (score 9):

The verb ***[leave](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave)*** could also work:

> 3
>
> - a :  to go away from :  depart ***(leave the room)***
> - b :  desert, abandon ***(left his wife)***
> - c :  to terminate association with :  withdraw from ***(left school before graduation)***

When you ***leave*** someone, you say goodbye.

Comment: Note that "to leave _with_ someone" is also perfectly capable of conveying an entirely different message!)))

Comment: "take your leave" works better

Answer (score -2):

Kind of a special case, but "dismiss" also works.